# element.replaceWith not working as expected in AngularJS Directive when the model is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table, element, replacewith

So I have an array  with objects:

```
var columns= [{label:"Column 1",value:"val 1"},{label:"Column 2",value:"val 2"}];
```

I have a directive as attribute of table data element.

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns" my-directibe column="column.label", value="column.value">
```

This is the directive:

```
    .directive("queryResult", function ($compile) {
    return {
      scope: {
        value:"=",
        column:"="
      },
      restrict: "AE",
      link:function(scope,elemnt){
        var tableData=angular.element('<td ng-bind="value"></td>');
        elemnt.replaceWith($compile(tableData)(scope))
      }
    }
  })
```

The expected result should be like and it's is like:

```
<td class="ng-scope">val 1</td>
```

The problem comes when I add additional result to the array and the array becomes with three elements. Then this works only for the last added element for the first two elements it's like:

```
<td query-result ng-repeat="column in columns" value="value" column="column" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"></td>
<td class="ng-scope">val 1</td>

<td query-result ng-repeat="column in columns" value="value" column="column" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"></td>
<td class="ng-scope">val 2</td>

<td class="ng-scope">val 3</td>
```

So these additional td creates additional columns with blank values and the whole table goes wrong.

Comment: try wrapping `elemnt.replaceWith($compile(tableData)(scope))` inside `$timeout` function will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `elemnt.replaceWith` will execute only once, so binding will not work at all.

Try this:

```
return {
  scope: {
    value:"=",
    column:"="
  },
  restrict: "AE",
  link:function(scope,elemnt){
    var tableData=angular.element('<td ng-bind="value"></td>');
    scope.$watch('value', function() {
        elemnt.replaceWith($compile(tableData)(scope));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Well this won't work because you are watching over the value. I'm not changing the value of the object but the array where the object reside.

From problem description there is columns array right. So i'm changing it.
As you can see I don't pass it nowhere to the directive so there is not way for listening to that change.